# how do you play world of tanks on ubuntu

Tags: games

how do you play wot on unbuntu.I`m new to linux os and know how to do about nothing on how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Just works under **wine** `3.21-staging` and up.
Current stable version is 4.0.

Based on wine [application database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11544), the game has gold status, which means it should work without any problems. If something turns out, check the [linked website](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=36493) for all the available workarounds.

---

### Install

If your system is `x64`, you need to enable `x86` architecture

```
sudo -i
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

**Download and add the repository key**

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
apt-key add winehq.key
```

**Add the repository based on your ubuntu version**

> One line here is one command for terminal. Use copy-paste.

`apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/` **`cosmic`**`main'`
`apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/` **`bionic`**`main'`
`apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/` **`xenial`**`main'`
`apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/` **`trusty`**`main'`

**Update packages** with `apt update`

**Install one of the following packages**

> Note, that there is **no space** between winehq-stable etc.

`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-`**`stable`**
`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-`**`devel`**
`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-`**`staging`**

Comment: it freezes up after you go through the downloading process.the loading whell just keeps turning endless

Comment: @macdaddym you need to install `staging` release. Updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.